# Get JS var value in HTML source using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a JavaScript var value from an HTML source code using BeautifulSoup.

For example I have:

```
<script>
[other code]
var my = 'hello';
var name = 'hi';
var is = 'halo';
[other code]
</script>
```

**I want something to return the value of the var "my" in Python**

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a *regular expression pattern* to both locate the element via `BeautifulSoup` and extract the desired substring:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<script>
[other code]
var my = 'hello';
var name = 'hi';
var is = 'halo';
[other code]
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r"var my = '(.*?)';$", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
```

Prints `hello`.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea would be to use a *JavaScript parser* and locate a variable declaration node, check the *identifier* to be of a desired value and extract the *initializer*. Example using [`slimit` parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


data = """
<script>
var my = 'hello';
var name = 'hi';
var is = 'halo';
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: text and "var my" in text)

# parse js
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(script.text)
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.VarDecl) and node.identifier.value == 'my':
        print(node.initializer.value)
```

Prints `hello`.

Comment: this solution does not work when the var is an array: `var my = ['hello', 'world']`

Answer (score 0):

the answer, `pattern = re.compile(r"var my = '(.*?)';$", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`
should get a wrong way, have to remove the line-end sign `$` when set `re.MULTILINE re.DOTALL` at same time.

try with python 3.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Building on @alecxe's answer, but considering a more complex case of an array of dictionaries - or an array of flat json objects:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


data = """
<script>
var my = [{'dic1key1':1}, {'dic2key1':1}];
var name = 'hi';
var is = 'halo';
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: text and "var my" in text)

# parse js
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(script.text)
array_items = []
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.VarDecl) and node.identifier.value == 'my':
        for item in node.initializer.items:
            parsed_dict = {getattr(n.left, 'value', '')[1:-1]: getattr(n.right, 'value', '')[1:-1]
                for n in nodevisitor.visit(item)
                if isinstance(n, slimit.ast.Assign)}
        array_items.append(parsed_dict)
print(array_items)
```