# Python Requests print HTML response variable

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I use below script to get the temporary code from server

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload{
'username':'demo',
'password':'demo'
}
with requests.session() as s:
    r= s.post(192.13.11.100,data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

No issues in script,

Now, I am getting the output as expected.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var session_key='d2e08508d3';
</script>
<script>
var temporary_data='01';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I wanted to get the session_key from the html output.

Please let me know how can I get the variable inside the html

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: You could try regex with r"session_key=['|\"]{1}([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})['|\"]{1}" on the html string and retrieve group 1

Comment: @benjababe, although regex MAY work in some very limited number of cases, it's [better not to use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4046632). But you can use regex, ONCE the text from the tag is extracted and then to obtain the specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse it using RegEx:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(".*?session_key\=\'(\S+)\'")
session_key = regex.search(r.text).group(1)
```

Here you can test the regular expression further: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/6c231)

Here you can find some documentation on the `search()` method: [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Answer (score 1):

Trye this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = f"""
<html>
<body>
<script>
var session_key='d2e08508d3';
</script>
<script>
var temporary_data='01';
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html)
session_key = re.findall(r"session_key='(.*?)'", soup.find("script").text)[0]
print(session_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer : [Get JS var value in HTML source using BeautifulSoup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020606/get-js-var-value-in-html-source-using-beautifulsoup-in-python/49460489)

You can do it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

data = """<html>
<body>
<script>
var session_key='d2e08508d3';
</script>
<script>
var temporary_data='01';
</script>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: text and "var session_key" in text)
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(script.text)
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.VarDecl) and node.identifier.value == 'session_key':
        print(node.initializer.value)
```

Please reward this answer for the work that he has done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020794/17077329